# Prevent Exchange 2013 from skipping large items (TooManyLargeItemsPermanentException)

Tags: mailbox, exchange-2013

I'm experimenting with Exchange 2013. After importing my mailbox using

```
 New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath \\path\import.pst -Mailbox test
```

I get the message, that importging completed with errors. With

```
Get-MailboxImportRequest | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics -IncludeReport | fl >report.txt
```

I can see, that TooManyLargeItemsPermanentException is thrown.
I have 4 mails, which are too big.

I saw that I can controll how many large items can be skipped by using

```
-LargeItemLimit -AcceptLargeDataLoss
```

But does anybody know what I have to do to import everything? I want to have those large eMails in my mailbox.

Answer (score 6):

The size limit on import is determined by the max message size settings in Exchange. To import larger mails, you will need to set max sizes using Powershell:

```
Set-TransportConfig -MaxSendSize 100MB -MaxReceiveSize 100MB
Get-ReceiveConnector | Set-ReceiveConnector -MaxMessageSize 100MB
Get-SendConnector | Set-SendConnector -MaxMessageSize 100MB
```

You then need to restart these services:

- Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Transport Delivery
- Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Transport Submission
- Microsoft Exchange Transport
- Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Assistants

Just adjust the message sizes larger if you need to import something bigger. Make sure to adjust back down once done importing if smaller limitations are desired.

Comment: Worked after reboot. It seems restarting those services isn't enough in Exchange 2016, otherwise it works.

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar when migrating to Exchange 2010 from 2003 last weekend.

I would suggest going through the integrity and repair (if necessary) process with `eseutil` on the mailbox store (if you're going from Exchange) or using [scanpst.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287497) from the Office directory if you're using just a PST.

If it still fails, run it with `BadItemLimit` and `AcceptLargeDataLoss`; the job will have a log file containing the date, subject, sender, and receiver of any corrupted message (just CTRL-F for "`<BadItem`") and from my experience, even massive mailboxes had only 10 or 11 corrupted items, tops.

It would be well worth it to note which items it's failing on and manually retrieving those (and if it is a large attachment, just save it as a file or open the PST from Outlook after migration and manually drag it in if you **really** want that large attachment in your inbox still).

Comment: Hey @gravyface, thanks for your reply. Well, the items inside the PST are too big. The log tells me, that the size limit is 35 MB, and I'm a bit obove with 4 maisl. The mails are not corrupted. I wanted to avoid manually importing the items, because i guess some of my colleagues will have big mails, too, and all have PSTs waiting to be imported. Is there a way I could raise the mail-size-cap?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and attempted to import the .pst using Outlook.  I can't recall the exact message I received but it made me think to change the maximum message receive size for the mailbox.  I changed it to 512000 and the import was successful.

I backtracked for some of the other mailboxes that had failed importing using the ECA and was able to perform imports on the mailboxes that were failing after I changed the setting for the mailbox.